# In Visualization Toolkit, which types of objects need Update() and Modified() to be called and when?

Tags: vtk

I'm looking at some VTK code which may not be working correctly. Here's a snippet:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera> cam = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera>::New();
cam->SetFocalPoint(0, 0, 0);
cam->SetViewUp(perp[0], perp[1], perp[2]);

cam->SetPosition(first_cam_pos);
cam->SetViewAngle(20);
cam->Modified();
```

It seems to me that the call to `Modified()` shouldn't be necessary, that calling the four Set functions should automatically signal that the camera has been modified.

Indeed, the [Kitware VTK camera example](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/Camera) doesn't use `Modified()` for the camera.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera> camera = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera>::New();
camera->SetPosition(0, 0, 20);
camera->SetFocalPoint(0, 0, 0);

// Create a renderer, render window, and interactor
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();

renderer->SetActiveCamera(camera);
```

In other cases, the potentially not-working VTK code I'm looking at uses `Update()` to manually update — not for the camera object, but elsewhere. Again, I think this is probably not necessary; but **clearly `Update()` and `Modified()` are there for some reason**.

**Is there some rule for determining when `Modified()` and `Update()` need to be called and when they don't?** Are there certain types of objects that need them and certain types that don't? Or is it related to the types of functions that are called on them?

I'm using VTK 6.1, but I'd love to get a general answer if there's some historical context here.

Answer (score 6):

Update() is required when you want to use an object before the pipeline updates it for you. An example is:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataReader> reader = \
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataReader>::New();

reader->SetFileName("myfile.vtp");

// At this point, the reader hasn't yet read the file, so the
// following line with result in polydata being null (or 
// something like that)

vtkPolyData* badPolydata = reader->GetOutput();

// However, once you tell the reader "update right now, don't wait
// for the pipeline to update you" with:

reader->Update();

// you can now get access to the data it has read:

vtkPolyData* goodPolydata = reader->GetOutput();
```

If, on the other hand, you are going to take the reader, attach it to a mapper, attach the mapper to an actor, and display the actor in the renderwindow, then at the time when the renderer says "Ok, now I need the data that drives this whole chain", the pipeline will go back and call Update() on the reader. This is the whole reason for/benefit of the pipeline execution model.

---

Modified() is required when you want to inform the pipeline "on the next pass, you need to re-process this object". This is done internally by most of the Set* functions, so I guess you just have to look at the implementation to see if Modified() is getting called or not by whatever function you've called that you expect to take effect the next pass through the pipeline.

Comment: But how do I know when the pipeline is telling something to update?

Comment: It is pretty situation-specific, but the general idea is that the pipeline updates an object when something "downstream" from it requests for it to be updated. The primary place you'll see this is when it is time to actually draw something on the screen (the last step in the pipeline), everything in the pipeline that is not up to date will have to be updated (because they all come before/are upstream from the rendering).

Comment: If I chain two things together in the pipeline, will the latter ask the former to update before getting from it? Or do I need to call update manually?

Comment: I am not a pipeline expert by any stretch, but in this case I'm pretty sure if you call update on the downstream filter, it will force the upstream filter to update. Try it and see :) Maybe add a vtkSmoothPolyDataFilter after a vtkSphereSource and call update on the smooth filter and see if the source actually generated the data that needed to be smoothed.

Comment: but there's no update() method in latest version of vtk, how may I do it now?